# Code error correction: If there exists $v \in ℤ_2^{dim(C)}$, such that $w \cdot G(v) \neq 0$, then: $\sum_{v \in ℤ_2^{dim(C)}} (-1)^{w \cdot G(v)}=0$

Tags: calculus

This question is about error correction.

We have a Code C and a generator matrix G, such that G(v) ranges over all the codewords in C as v ranges over all the words in $ℤ_2^{\dim(C)}$.

I want to prove the following statement:

- If there exists $v \in ℤ_2^{\dim(C)}$, such that $w \cdot G(v) \neq 0$, then: $\sum_{v \in ℤ_2^{\dim(C)}} (-1)^{w \cdot G(v)}=0$

I don't know how to start proving it. The thing I don't get is: this is only $0$, if I have as many $1$'s as $-1$'s, but if there is only one $v \in ℤ_2^{\dim(C)}$, such that $w \cdot G(v) \neq 0$, how can it add up to $0$? I should have $\dim(C)-1$ ones then and only one $-1$...

Comment: Hi Aurora. What have you tried, if anything? If you share this by Editing above, people here won't need to show you things you already know. By the way, you can use MathJax dollar signs to typeset your title as well as your main text.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:quantum-information] and [tag:quantum-computation]; is there some underlying physical context? Also, what are $C,w,G(v)$?